# how can I call multiple columns from my data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, lines-of-code

I'm trying to get the top 10 longest songs in my data frame by calling two columns using the code  `df.loc[['duration_min','name']].head()`. I have already sorted the relevant columns by descending order but when I run the code, I keep getting this error:

> KeyError: "None of [Index(['duration_min', 'name'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

I was expecting the code to run without any problems

Comment: Use: `df[['duration_min','name']].head(10)`, `loc` with 1 parameter is for indices

Comment: You need to use: `df.loc[:, ['duration_min', 'name']]`, if you don't supply ':', `loc` thinks it is an index and tries to find it in the index.

Comment: adding the semi colon worked perfectly. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Error shows that there are no indices called 'duration_min' and 'name'. You should use:

```
df[['duration_min', 'name']].head(x)
```

with x, an integer.